# Running jq on a remote machine over ssh and overwrite the file

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, jq

I am trying to create a file from the output of `jq` command over ssh command.

```
ssh <server-Name> "jq '.credsStore = "ecr-login"' ~/.docker/config.json > ~/.docker/output.json "
```

It gives me following error:

`bash: .docker/output.json: No such file or directory`

Am I not running the command properly or is there any other problem?

Comment: For starters, the command you're attempting to send contains unescaped double quotes...

Comment: Which quotes you are referring to? @JeffMercado

Comment: @BhavikJoshi: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh "$server" "bash -s" <<'EOF'
[[ -e ~/.docker/config.json ]] || {
  echo "ERROR: $HOME/.docker/config.json does not exist on the remote server" >&2
  exit 1
}

jq '.credsStore = "ecr-login"' \
  <~/.docker/config.json \
  >~/.docker/output.json 
EOF
```